# Reputation Points on comment votes

Tags: discussion

I understand that upvoting someone's comment will not give them any reputation points, and I'm fine with that. **I have no desire to change this functionality.**

However, I AM curious - what was the original reason for setting it up that way and not, say, give someone 1 rep point each time their comment gets upvoted?

Comment: This would probably be better on meta.stackexchange

Comment: @SSumner you mean: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197642/165776

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - would that be the answer to my question then? That comments were never meant to award rep, because that's something that only proper questions & answers should do?

Comment: Yes but I'll expand on it in an answer, gimme a sec.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There have been occasional questions about this on the meta.stachexchange, or back when it was meta.stackoverflow, including this answer that explains why they aren't going to *change* the behavior.

[Reputation for comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments/197642#197642)

The answer there doesn't come right out and say it, but the reason that comments don't have rep is because rep is for *good questions and good answers*. There's really no such this as a "good comment" or "bad comment", apart from obvious policy violations (spam, harrassment, etc).

The idea of comments is that they are transitory. After a while, you don't even see them; in fact, it's not uncommon for users to go back and delete old comments, or for moderators to come in and delete comments *en masse* when thy get particularly out of hand. That kind of variability would play havoc with a rep system.

Getting reputation for comments would essentially elevate them to the same level as questions and answers, when they are purposefully intended to be second-class citizens. We don't *want* people getting a "reputation" for being a really good commenter, because ultimately that doesn't advance the goal of Stack Exchange: to explicitly *not* be a comments forum.

Lastly, if you allowed + rep points for comment upvotes, you'd ultimately need to allow - rep points for comment downvotes, but it's not clear what a downvote on a comment would mean. Comments often contain opinions, suggestions, or requests for clarification -- we don't want people penalized for making suggestions that just happen to turn out to be bad.

Comment: Additionally, some comments get a lot of upvotes for being funny. Being funny is not the same as being helpful.

Comment: @phantom42 See: Clowns versus Politicians.  One is only good for laughing at, and the other is a clown.

Comment: Notable: if the primary purpose of comments is to inform useful edits to questions and answers (and it is), then we get rep for *acting on comments*, as peer-reviewed edits grant small amounts of reputation.

Comment: @BESW But not for editing *your own* question, and comments are mainly to notify the OP, not random passersby, of useful edits.

Comment: Worthy comments and dutiful posters means ultimately if a comment is useful, the information will migrate back into the answer thus improving the overall information quality of the site in general.